# status 302 - error document move (HTTP advanced)

Tags: http, ionic3

I'm trying to do get request, but get **status:302,  error: document moved**.
I'm using plugin **cordova-plugin-advanced-http 2.3.1 "Advanced HTTP plugin"** When I test the url using postman, it worked.

Here is my code

```html
  public testHttp(){

    this.http.get(
     'https://www.example/test/1', {}, {}
   )
    .then(response => {
       // prints 200
       console.log("succs");
       console.log(response);
       try {
         response.data = JSON.parse(response.data);
         console.log(response.data.message);
       } catch(e) {
         console.error('JSON parsing error');
       }
    })
    .catch(response => {
      // prints 403
      console.log("err");
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
```

This is my ionic info

```html
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 5.4.13 (C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.9
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 6 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 0.3.0

System:

   NodeJS : v8.9.4 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.12.1
   OS     : Windows 10
```

What does the error mean and how to fix it?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-advanced-http#setfollowredirect

Comment: I need to enable SSL pinning?

Comment: No, you need to enable following redirects.